# What is the mission of stripe objects metadata field?

Tags: java, stripe-payments

In [API description](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#create_recipient) for Java, I found next info:

> metadata optional, default is { }
>
> A set of key/value pairs that you can attach to a recipient object. It
>   can be useful for storing additional information about the recipient
>   in a structured format.

Does it impact payment process? Does this data processed by Stripe system?

Comment: Metadata is used for your own use, to my knowledge it does not play into Stripe's machine learning algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All updatable Stripe objects support a `metadata` field that you can use to store arbitrary key/value pairs.

This information is not used by Stripe at all: it's there for your own use. For instance, you could use metadata to attach an internal order ID to every charge you create. This could help with accounting purposes or simply for clarity when viewing the charge in your dashboard.

You can find the documentation for metadata here: https://stripe.com/docs/api#metadata

Comment: Metadata can now be added/modified via the Dashboard.